# How to install mysql in powershell?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have tried multiple ways to get `mysql` installed so I can use `mysqldump` in a Windows Powershell script (ran in an Azure function).

I tried to choco to install `mysql`, but kept getting powershell errors: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ChocoMan/1.2.5

(added `ChocoMan` to `requirements.psd1` of function app)

```
Install-ChocoPackage -Name mysql
```

I tried to install the mysql install zip directly from https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.3/mysql-8.3.0-winx64.zip, however, keep getting a 403 response with text saying "technical difficulties with oracle" even though it downloads fine if I curled from my local machine or downloaded from the link myself.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.3/mysql-8.3.0-winx64.zip" -OutFile "mysql.zip"
```

What am I missing to install `mysql` in powershell?

Comment: see https://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2021/04/27/mysql-ps-connection/ and lots of more such pages

Comment: That is different, they are using `.Net`?

Comment: no they use the dotnet connector dll to work with powershell

Comment: It's not clear in that doc how they actually install mysql?

Comment: For clarity, I am not running this powershell script locally, but from an azure function.

Comment: maybe this makes it clearer https://www.techtrek.io/connecting-powershell-to-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using chocolatey like you should.

This [doc](https://chocolatey.org/install) shows how to install chocolatey and it should be relatively easy.

Once this is done, you should be able to install mysql easily throught chocolatey with the command [choco install mysql](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/mysql). Though it is not up to date.

I don't think you need that ChocoMan tool.